# Completely lost with a project regarding 2D arrays and random number generation

Tags: java, arrays, random, 2d

I need to fill a 2D array with random numbers 1-5. The random numbers must be generated using the system time in nanoseconds. It's a bit more complicated though

Let's say the array has 5 rows 5 columns, this would be displayed as

```
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
```

Then (i'm thinking) a for loop would be used to generate the 1-5 to fill the array. The array must be filled from the front (row 1) to the back. The complication is that the first time elements are placed into the array, it is 001. So if the first random number is 1, the array would then look like

```
001 ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
```

Then let's say the next number is 4 (The second time elements are placed into the array). This appears as

```
001 002 002 002 002
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
```

However, if that number had been a 5 it wouldn't have fit. All elements must be placed consecutively. If it had been a 5, the array would need to be

```
001 ... ... ... ...
002 002 002 002 002
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
```

and if the next number is 4, you would then fill in 003 next to the 001.

The actual array is 20x20. I'm completely lost as to how to do this. I'm not depending entirely on stackoverflow for help, I have tried it myself.

The problem needs to be solved in a non-concrete way, so that if certain circumstances were to change the program can be easily edited, such as changing the array dimensions. So I have

int randomNumber;

int dim1 = 20;

int dim2 = 20;

int[][] theater = new int[dim1][dim2];

Random r = new Random(System.nanoTime);

I need something about r.nextInt(5) +1;
I think but I'm not sure where to put it.

Comment: should this problem simulate memory fragmentation in a computer?

Comment: The purpose is to simulate theater seating, so theres like 20 rows of 20 seats and people prefer to sit in the closest rows to the stage but people that request tickets MUST sit next to one another, you can't go to the next row.

Comment: okay, i wrote some example code for the problem. check if that could work

Comment: This seems to be an example of a [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). Look into methods for solving that.

Comment: Since I'm fairly certain this is a homework problem I'm going to give you advice instead of code. Keep a separete 1D array to store how many occupied values are in each row.  That value can be used to both to check if there's enough room for a placement there and to know where to start placing values if there is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need a structure something like this? I hope I understood the problem correctly.

```
int number = Random.nextInt(5) + 1;

for(int i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
    boolean place = false;
    int index = 0;
    while(!place){
        int room = -1;
        if(rows[index] != 0){
            index++;
        }
        else{
            room = rows.length - index;
            place = true;
        }
    }
    if(number <= room){
        placestuff(i, index);
    }
}
```